# Getting a different result while converting dict object into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

f is the dict which i get from calling a function. But while i am trying to convert f dict object into pandas dataframe.
Below is the code

```
f=get_frequencies(g, p)
print(f)
```

This is the output of dict object f

```
{'close4':      close1  close2  close3  ...  pclose2_close4  pclose3_close4  pclose4_close4
0         0       0       0  ...        0.194444        0.262295        0.169231
1         0       0       0  ...        0.472222        0.475410        0.476923
2         0       0       0  ...        0.333333        0.262295        0.353846
3         0       0       1  ...        0.472222        0.578125        0.476923
4         0       0       1  ...        0.333333        0.260417        0.353846
..      ...     ...     ...  ...             ...             ...             ...
96        2       2       1  ...        0.187500        0.260417        0.264368
97        2       2       2  ...        0.541667        0.585106        0.605128
98        2       2       2  ...        0.187500        0.223404        0.210256
99        2       2       2  ...        0.270833        0.191489        0.206897
100       2       2       2  ...        0.541667        0.585106        0.528736

[101 rows x 10 columns]}
```

Below is the code for conversion of dict into pandas dataframe

```
dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(f, orient='index').T
print(dff)
```

This is the output after conversion of disc object f into pandas dataframe.

```
                                              close4
0       close1  close2  close3  ...  pclose2_clos...
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Which form does the dictionary `f` have? It looks like there is one key and then a very structured object. This could be the reason for pandas to create a one-row DataFrame.

Comment: Expected output is like dictionary of f.

Comment: This is built in dictionary